# Django url regular expression matching but page not found error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, file-not-found

Project Name: JalaBapa_website

JalaBapa_website\urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about_us/', include('About_Us.urls')),
    url(r'^activities/', include('Activities.urls')),
    url(r'^collections/', include('Collections.urls')),
    url(r'^contact_us/', include('Contact_Us.urls')),
    url(r'^donate/', include('Donate.urls')),
    url(r'^events/', include('Events.urls')),
    url(r'^home/', include('Home.urls')),
    url(r'^publications/', include('Publications.urls')),
]
```

Publications/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "Publications"

urlpatterns = [
    # /publications/
    url(r'^$', views.publications, name='publications'),
    # /publications/Xyz_9999.pdf/
    url(r'(?P<file_name>^[A-Z][a-z]+\_[0-9]{4}\.pdf$)', views.pdfs, name='pdfs')
]
```

Publications/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, FileResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import *
# Create your views here.


def publications(request):

    all_files = Publications.objects.all()
    uploaded_file_names = []
    for obj in all_files:
        uploaded_file_names.append(str(obj.file_name()))
        context = {
        'uploaded_file_names': uploaded_file_names
        }
    return render(request, 'publications/publications.html', context)


def pdfs(request, file_name):
    with open('media/pdfs/'+file_name, 'r') as pdf:
        response = FileResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        return response
```

some code of: Publications/templates/publications/publications.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for file_name in uploaded_file_names %}
    <a href="{{ file_name }}">
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'Publications:pdfs' file_name %}">
```

will be continued...

the above line in snippet was COMMENTED BECAUSE BEFORE THIS WAS SHOWING ERROR :

NoReverseMatch at /publications/

Reverse for 'pdfs' with arguments '('July_2017',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['publications/(?P^[A-Z][a-z]+\_[0-9]{4}\.pdf$)']

[Here is Error Screen Shot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeWuU.png)

> I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHY THIS IS NOT WORKING - QUESTION 1

ANYHOW, `<a href="{{ file_name }}">` was hardcoded but running so I moved on temporarily

Continuing the above file left half way...

```
        <div style="float: left;" class="boxes black-container text-grow">
            {{ file_name }}
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

> QUESTION - 2: In just above file publications.html, when I click on `{{ file_name }}`, it shows me error 404 page not found, [here is screen shot of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjaFY.png)

The Link: `127.0.0.1:8000/publications/July_2017`

The url matching is:  `url(r'^publications/', include('Publications.urls'))` and  `url(r'(?P<file_name>^[A-Z][a-z]+\_[0-9]{4}\.pdf$)', views.pdfs, name='pdfs')`

While, when I went on `https://www.regextester.com/88429` website it shows me that my file_name : `July_2017.pdf` matches with Regular Expression : `^\[A-Z\]\[a-z\]+\_\[0-9\]{4}\.pdf$`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answers - I'm not very confident with django, but I don't have enough reputation to only place a comment.

Question 1. Your placement of the caret ('^') looks different to mine - I've really only ever seen it as the first character inside the quotes (e.g. r'^publications/(?P etc etc. I can't see that this would cause the problem, but it might be something to try.

Question 2, the view 'pdfs' is trying to serve a FileResponse object but is your filename variable ('July_2017') stripped of the '.pdf' extension that will allow it to hit the file successfully?

Comment: Thanks Atcrank, and also I will try to figure out the first question problem.